# java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long with an array

Tags: java, arrays, casting

I'm trying to loop through a  userSet with where the id's in the array userSet are Int.  I keep getting this error: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Is there a simple way to do this?  Casting variables are easy but is there an easy way to cast all variables in an array to Long?  Very new to Java here.

```
Set <Long> userSet = getUniqueFollowers("/tmp/followers.txt")

for (long id : userSet) {
     System.out.println("Starting twitter account: " + id);
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want them to be `long`? Because it seems to me that you could just use `int` and it would work.

Comment: First, as you've clearly discovered you **can't** do it with a cast. Second, what does `getUniqueFollowers` return? --- `Set<Integer>`?

Comment: Also a `Set` is not an array

Answer (score 0):

Parameterization of collection intended right to not getting cast-exceptions and to know type of elements of collection, to know "what is inside" (however you can hide parameter-type at will)

So "set of integers" can not be cast to "set of longs" straight. You only can create a new set and fill it with elements one by one.

Anyway, why do you need to cast collection to `Set<Long>`? Why not `Set<Integer>` (as I understand — what is the return type of method). 
Or, as I said, you may hide param and just type `Set userSet = ...`